# unable to display data using parametrized query with c#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, prepared-statement

I am trying to display the data using parametrized query

```
try
{
 SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection();
 xconn.ConnectionString = @" Data Source=servername; Database=master; Trusted_Connection=yes ";
 xconn.Open();
 SqlCommand ycmd = new SqlCommand ("select * from tablename where column1 = @name", xconn);
 ycmd.Parameters.Add("@name", dropdownlist.SelectedValue);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s,xconn);
 SqlCommandBuilder cmdbuilder  = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 gridview.DataSource = dt;
 gridview.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  label.Text = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace;
 }
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: is there an exception??are you sure you are executing the command ??

Comment: whats happening after execcuting? whats the error you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
try 
{ 
 SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection(); 
 xconn.ConnectionString = @" Data Source=servername; Database=master; Trusted_Connection=yes";
 SqlCommand ycmd = new SqlCommand ("select * from tablename where column1 = @name", xconn); 
 ycmd.Parameters.Add("@name", dropdownlist.SelectedValue); 
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ycmd);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
 da.Fill(dt); 
 gridview.DataSource = dt; 
 gridview.DataBind(); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{ 
  label.Text = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace; 
}
```

You don't need to call `SqlConnection.Open()` when you are using the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method.  In that method it opens up the connection and disposes/closes it when complete. (this isn't the problem, just an FYI)

The way you created your `SqlDataAdapter` is the problem.  You didn't create it with the `SqlCommand` as a constructor, just the command text.  Because of that, you didn't pass in the parameter that was specified in the `SqlCommand` class.

Let me know if that works.  And if that doesn't work, try manually running this query in SSMS to ensure that it actually returns a result set.  Also, make sure that your `ListControl.SelectedValue` property contains something.  Do this by debugging and analyze what is stored there.